# Active noise cancellation not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, filter, noise

I have been trying to construct my own noise-canceling headphones. I have tried 2 different circuits and even combined the 2 with my own knowledge of analog electronics. Please see the links below if you would like to see the full description of the product.

The one on Instructables uses a phase delay using an all-pass filter, and an inverting summing amplifier at the end, I have done many variations to the all-pass filter with no luck on any noise reduction. see an image of circuit below:
[image]

The second one makes use of a 180-degree phase inversion, it doesn't have an effect on noise reduction it just amplifies the noise, see an image below.
[image]

I have tested the circuits with a single sine wave and all the components function as it should and the microphones work, I have tested everything using an oscilloscope but still no luck.

Could you please give me some advice on what to look out for or what could possibly be the reason so that I can investigate this issue.

link 1 : https://www.instructables.com/id/Analog-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones/

link 2 : http://www4.ncsu.edu/~rsmith/MA574_S15/silence.pdf

Comment: I do not understand how this design should work. Noise cancelling is much more complicated than inverting the signal and feeding it to the ear. You need to take in account a lot of factors, the circuits you have found might work with luck and in very specific conditions...

Comment: Could you advise me on how I should go about this project than, like what approach should I take, analog/digital and what type of components should I look at?

Comment: Start with acoustics. Sound propagation speed and reflections in materials and the interface between them. You should probably make a 3D model of your headphones and a standard head, and computer simulate the system with different sound sources at different frequencies. Some frequencies will be canceled passively by the materials and geometry of the system, others will need active cancelling. Some might be amplified by the acoustics of your phones, in which case you should prob change the design. If you make a mistake, the active circuit might introduce or amplify noise instead of removing it.

Comment: As far as I know all noise cancelling products use some kind of DSP (Digital Signal Processor). If it was possible with a circuit like yours the for sure that would be used as DSPs are more expensive and require algorithms which need to be written by someone who understands noise cancelling.

Comment: If you look closely the linked paper ([2]), they say that the effectiveness of the circuit was proven measuring with a scope the input and the output, and that the headphones worked "fairly well". Which, at best, does not mean anything.

Comment: Well, their test "music" is really just a single tone, and they also realize that "broadband noise sources" experience a perceived shift to (usually more annoying) higher frequencies. So my conclusion to that would've been "works as badly as expected", not "works pretty good". But then again, for a beginner's electronic project (and I'm guessing they are beginners, advanced electronics guys usually don't try to introduce the loop and junction rule of voltages and currents), this is indeed pretty nice!